# Matching of positive to negative numbers in the same group - R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to do the following thing:

```
id calendar_week value
1    1              10
2    2              2
3    2             -2
4    2              3
5    3              10 
6    3             -10
```

The output which I want is the list of id (or the rows) which have a positiv to negative match for a given calendar_week -> which means I want for example the id 2 and 3 because there is a match of -2 to 2 in Calendar week 2. I don't want id 4 because there is no -3 value in calendar week 2 and so on.

output:

```
id calendar_week value 
2    2              2
3    2             -2
5    3              10 
6    3             -10
```

Comment: How do you get 10 and -10 in the final output?

Comment: Are values within calendar week unique?

Comment: same calendar week and a match of 10 to the negative of 10

Comment: can it have 2 same values?  2, 2, etc? what would be your output in that case? Do you want to select those rows?

Comment: But the IDs are different? What does 'the same group' then mean?

Comment: @H1 hmm could be that not always but in general it should be. Then only one match would be enough

Comment: @RonakShah that I need just one match the other could be ignored

Comment: same group is the same calendar_week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could also do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(calendar_week, ab = abs(value)) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-ab)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id calendar_week value
  <int>         <int> <int>
1     2             2     2
2     3             2    -2
3     5             3    10
4     6             3   -10
```

Given your additional clarifications, you could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(calendar_week, value) %>%
  mutate(idx = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(calendar_week, idx, ab = abs(value)) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-idx, -ab)
```

On a modified data frame:

```
  id calendar_week value
1  1             1    10
2  2             2     2
3  3             2    -2
4  3             2     2
5  4             2     3
6  5             3    10
7  6             3   -10
8  7             4    10
9  8             4    10
```

This gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id calendar_week value
  <int>         <int> <int>
1     2             2     2
2     3             2    -2
3     5             3    10
4     6             3   -10
```

Comment: this is good! how would you adjust it to have all matches in it? for example if in the same week we have more matches of 2 to -2?

Comment: This would output all matches by default. If you'd have e.g. `2, -2, 2, -2`, it would just output all of them. It'd also output if you'd have `2, -2, 2` - if you don't want to output this last row then you'd need additional configuration but this has not been specified in the question.

Comment: that is true! I don't want the last one. Do you know the additional configurations?

Comment: This answer doesn't match positive and negative, just duplicated absolute values.  It would also return a match of 10, 10 for example.

Comment: @Henryk Borzymowski, of course, see my edit. @H 1 the solution matches the example, authors of posts should take care of sufficient complexity, but I've adjusted my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(calendar_week) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(values = map_chr(data, ~ str_c(.x$value, collapse = ', '))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(str_detect(values, as.character(-value))) %>%
  select(-values)
```

Output :

```
calendar_week    id value
          <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1             2     2     2
2             2     3    -2
3             3     5    10
4             3     6   -10
```

Answer (score 1):

If as stated in the comments only a single match is required you could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(calendar_week, nvalue = abs(value)) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(value)) %>%
  filter(sum(value) == 0) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-nvalue)

     id calendar_week value
  <int>         <int> <int>
1     2             2     2
2     3             2    -2
3     5             3   -10
4     6             3    10
```